# UPDATE on a domain object which was created with a JOIN

Tags: sql, orm, jakarta-ee, domain-driven-design

How is this situation typically handled?  I have a domain object which contains data which is the result of a join between 2 tables; how should the update be handled?

One approach is to have TableADao, TableBDao (1to1 table-Dao relationship) and have the domain object constructed by a Repository class which effectively handles the relationship (join & batch update).

Is there a better way? Using a JOIN seems way more efficient. The 2 tables are very small, but are part of a legacy DB i must support & cannot change.

How do ORM's handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view and you can update that as if it were one table.

Comment: this would certainly solve my issue, but I wonder how this will work with the no DB modifications requirement.  Can I do this in a way that they are disposable, eg. a Dao creates the view at instantiation & then deletes it upon being destroyed?  Also is this db implementation specific? Right now i'm supporting oracle 10/11g only but will eventually be supporting MSSQL, MySql, and hopefully we can get close to being totally DB implementation independant

Comment: I'm not sure, you might want to ask on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the ORM you are using. It may or may not support aggregate objects and/or mapped views.

Comment: Unfortunately (or maybe not, as I keep reading about how ORM's are really uncool, at least from a DBA's perspective) I can't use a true ORM because of the poor database design.  Specifically, once deployed it must be able to handle changes to database schema which doesn't bode well for static db->domain mappings.  Right now I'm using Apache DBUtils with a custom resolver which maps some known cols to bean properties, throws everything else in a map, and relies on safe accessor methods to prevent NPE's.

Comment: Whenever a db schema changes, it should not cause breaking changes in the existing code, right...? If tables are added, ORMs can handle that. If fields are added or renamed, ORMs can handle that too. Basically any change can be handled or covered by using views. But the fact remains that maintaining crappy legacy apps sucks :-/